# What is the best way to repeatedly call a method that fetches json from a remote server(iOS)

Tags: ios

Im a newbie to iOS. I need some guidance on which is the best way to retrieve json every 5 sec from a remote server both, when in foreground or background, so that the UI gets updated properly regardless of the state. For example: Similar to a live cricket score app for iOS.

Any leads will help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this when the application is in the background for more than a few seconds! Additionally, polling is no good approach to accomplish this. Users won't love your app because it drains the battery fast.

Comment: Thanks CouchDeveloper. What do i do when the user gets a call or gets off the app. Currently I'm stopping timer in the applicationWillResignActive: and then in the applicationDidBecomeActive:, i have added [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"didBecomeActive"
                                                        object: nil
                                                      userInfo: nil];
controller=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Actually you could do this with iOS 7 background fetch feature.iOS 7 supports two new background execution modes for apps. Apps that regularly update their content by contacting a server can register with the system and be launched periodically to retrieve that content in the background.

Comment: First off, you should not use a timer for this. Read @Joride's answer which points you in the right direction.

Comment: @whitewolf09 You are correct, but this is not polling via a timer. In fact, background fetch *may* be a viable approach for the OPs task. However, the app has no control how and when and how often this update occurs.

Comment: Yes i did. But then iOS7 terminates the background task if it runs out of memory isn't it?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper agreed. Apperently the best solution for this would be the other background execution method available in iOS 7. Which is push notification based method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use background fetching, a system-supplied way of efficiently polling. Think in terms of minutes to hours between each poll. Otherwise, use silent push notification: it will wake up the app to do actual downloading. Read on if you are trying to do this for an actual app that you want in the app store.

Facebook app uses this push-to-download AND also abuses this feature to poll to often, thus draining the battery. That is why most people will turn this feature off for Facebook and hence there is then NO polling at all anymore. So be careful with how much energy you consume for a real app.

Answer (score 1):

For fetching data from background you can use BackgroundFectch mechanism.
All you need to do is

1. In appdelegate class you have to set the time interval.

> ```
>        - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
> {
>     [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];//default fetch interval is never,
>
>     return YES;
> }
> ```

1. Enable the app for background fetch

> ```
> Target->Capabilities->backgroundModes->backgroundFetch
> ```

3.Final step is implement the following method in app delegate class.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Hope this will help you .

There is one [sample app](https://github.com/jayaprada-behera/BackGroundFetchData) in Gitgub in which NSXmlParser is used .You can refer that .

Comment: But with this approach, app has no control how and when and how often it gets updated isn't it?

Comment: @user3167911 we are setting the value for minimumFetchInterval in didFinishLaunching method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSTimer` for repeatedly performing actions::

The following class method will help you:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti 
                                     target:(id)aTarget 
                                   selector:(SEL)aSelector
                                   userInfo:(id)userInfo 
                                    repeats:(BOOL)yesOrNo;
```

Use `repeats:YES`.

Comment: Thanks Anoop. I am using this method for repeated selector call. It works fine. But my concern is when the user gets off this app or gets a call.

Comment: in that case you have different delegate methods which gets called when you get a call, from there you need to initiate this again

Comment: applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 you have a new background execution method which helps in a situation like this.

*Apps that use push notifications to notify the user that new content is available can fetch the content in the background. To support this mode, include the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the remote-notification value in your app’s Info.plist file. You must also implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method in your app delegate.*

So you could send push notification from a server in a timely manner so app can be configured to do the background execution and fetching data.